# Android studio proxy settings

Tags: android-studio

I'm using ubuntu 16 and I downloaded and installed the last version of android-studio (file android-studio-ide-181.5056338-linux.zip).

I'm running android-studio behind a corporate proxy. I unzipped the file and I launched the `studio.sh` and I configured the proxy by following these links https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config#proxy and link https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2018.1/settings-http-proxy.html

Note I configured also my proxy authentication (both username and password) as showed in this image:

[image]

When I check the connection if I use some unsecure URLs (e.g. http://www.google.it) all works pretty good; the check is OK. If I use secure URLs (e.g. https://www.google.it) I get a 407 error (authentication required)
as showed in this image

[image]

Then I saved the settings and closed the IDE. Note I created no project yet... I just installed the IDE.

Now every time I start the IDE in the idea.log I see the following error:

```
2018-10-24 10:21:40,985 [e-1136-b06]   INFO - CompilerWorkspaceConfiguration - Available processors: 4 
2018-10-24 10:21:48,630 [d thread 2]   INFO - ateSettings.impl.UpdateChecker - Status: 407 
com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests$HttpStatusException: Status: 407. Status=407, Url=https://dl.google.com/android/studio/patches/updates.xml?uid=a40d2545-8f35-41af-bfbd-4bb898d2dc21&os=Linux+4.4.0-138-generic&build=AI-181.5540.7.32.5056338
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.openConnection(HttpRequests.java:512)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.access$300(HttpRequests.java:49)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests$RequestImpl.getConnection(HttpRequests.java:278)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests$RequestImpl.getInputStream(HttpRequests.java:287)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests$RequestImpl.getReader(HttpRequests.java:305)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests$RequestImpl.getReader(HttpRequests.java:298)
    at com.intellij.openapi.updateSettings.impl.UpdateChecker$checkPlatformUpdate$1.process(UpdateChecker.kt:176)
    at com.intellij.openapi.updateSettings.impl.UpdateChecker$checkPlatformUpdate$1.process(UpdateChecker.kt:54)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.lambda$doProcess$0(HttpRequests.java:403)
    at com.intellij.util.net.ssl.CertificateManager.runWithUntrustedCertificateStrategy(CertificateManager.java:335)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.doProcess(HttpRequests.java:403)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.process(HttpRequests.java:383)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.access$100(HttpRequests.java:49)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests$RequestBuilderImpl.connect(HttpRequests.java:252)
    at com.intellij.openapi.updateSettings.impl.UpdateChecker.checkPlatformUpdate(UpdateChecker.kt:174)
    at com.intellij.openapi.updateSettings.impl.UpdateChecker.doUpdateAndShowResult(UpdateChecker.kt:120)
    at com.intellij.openapi.updateSettings.impl.UpdateChecker.access$doUpdateAndShowResult(UpdateChecker.kt:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.updateSettings.impl.UpdateChecker$updateAndShowResult$2.run(UpdateChecker.kt:97)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:750)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$5.run(CoreProgressManager.java:434)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$1(CoreProgressManager.java:157)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:580)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:525)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:85)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:144)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.lambda$null$10(ApplicationImpl.java:565)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:305)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2018-10-24 10:21:48,631 [d thread 2]   INFO - ateSettings.impl.UpdateChecker - Connection failed (Status: 407). Please check network connection and try again.
```

So it seems that my proxy settings are not used by the update phase. Note i tried also to use unsecure connections but the error remains.

Ho can I solve this issue?

Thank you

Angelo

Answer (score 0):

Try this. 
[Change your Proxy settings like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHZk2.png)

And test your connection again.

https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config#proxy